# How do i specify variable as alt attribute in a liquid HTML filter

Tags: for-loop, shopify, liquid

Im trying to append the name of the variable in img alt attribute,
from the official documentation, they're hard-code the alt text.

is there any working solution?

```
{% for product in products %}
  {{ product | img_tag: 'Picture of {{ product.name }}' }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You must do your logic outside and pass it as a variable.

```
{% for product in products %}
  {%- capture image_alt -%}Picture of {{ product.title }}{%- endcapture -%}
  {{ product | img_tag: image_alt }} 
{% endfor %}
```

And there is no `product.name` object but there is `product.title`.